# Функция, которая будет возвращать сумму значений одинаковых ключей

Tags: python, python-3.x

Уже несколько дней не могу решить задачу, помогите пожалуйста:

Напишите функцию `elections()`, принимающую на вход несколько кортежей, в каждом из которых два элемента: первый элемент это фамилия кандидата, а второй — число голосов, отданных за него в каком-то из штатов. Подведите итоги выборов: верните словарь, ключами которого будут фамилии кандидатов, а значениями — общее число голосов (выборщиков), которое они получили на этих выборах.

```
assert elections( ('McCain', 10),('McCain', 5),('Obama', 9), ('Obama', 8), ('McCain', 1) )=={'McCain': 16, 'Obama': 17}
```

Благодарю.

Comment: за несколько дней ни одной строчки кода и даже не удалось нагуглить решение такой стандартной задачи? Весьма подозрительно.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: @Эникейщик, MarianD конечно есть код, но всё, что я смог сделать - x = [i for i in k for i in i] и отсортировать. А вот как оставить два ключа, а их значения суммировать - вообще никак. В интернете нашёл только решение, в котором нужно самому вводить данные, но это не то.

Comment: @MarianD у меня ушло около недели и больше 70 комментариев получилось, пока пытался решить задачу это ещё те, которые сохранились. =(

Comment: @SultanTapi, ради бога, добавите ваше (частичное) решение в ваш вопрос, *чтобы его не закрыли!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def elections(a: tuple) -> dict:
    res = {}
    for i in a:
        res.setdefault(i[0],0)
        res[i[0]] += i[1]
    return res
```

Проверяем:

```
a = ( ('McCain', 10),('McCain', 5),('Obama', 9), ('Obama', 8), ('McCain', 1) )
print(elections(a))
```

получаем:

```
{'McCain': 16, 'Obama': 17}
```

Comment: Ахереть! Вот это мэджик!=D Благодарю!

Comment: (a: tuple) -> dict: - что это за чудо такое???

Comment: setdefault - про это я тоже только узнал, хотя много сайтов посетил, где о словарях написано.=\

Comment: (a: tuple) -> dict: - это информация о принимаемом и возвращаемом функцией типе данных. обязательной не является, служит для ясности и удобства самого разработчика.

Comment: благодарю за разъяснение!

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, value in list_:
    try:
        dict_[key] += value
    except KeyError:
        dict_[key] = value
```

Comment: благодарю за ответ! Пробовал, но что-то не получается.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def elections(*data):
  last_names = {elem[0] for elem in data}

  return {
    lname :
    sum(elem[1] for elem in filter(lambda x: x[0] == lname, data))
    for lname in last_names
  }


print(elections(  ('McCain', 10), ('McCain', 5), ('Obama', 9), ('Obama', 8), ('McCain', 1)  ))
```

Результат

```
{'Obama': 17, 'McCain': 16}
```

Comment: Получилось! Супер! Код, конечно не для новичков, вроде меня, а решение прикольное. Буду разбираться, что за filter и с чем его едят. Благодарю.